# Callback in C++, template member? (2)

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, callback, pointer-to-member

The following callback class is a generic wrapper to "callable things". I really like its API, which has no templates and is very clean, but under the hood there is some dynamic allocation which I was not able to avoid.

Is there any way to get rid of the **new** and **delete** in the code below while maintaining the semantics and API of the callback class? I really wish I could.

---

**Needed stuff:**

```
// base class for something we can "call"
class callable {
  public:
  virtual void operator()() = 0;
  virtual ~callable() {}
};

// wraps pointer-to-members
template<class C>
class callable_from_object : public callable {
  public:
  callable_from_object(C& object, void (C::*method)())
         : o(object), m(method) {}

  void operator()() {
    (&o ->* m) ();
  }
  private:
  C& o;
  void (C::*m)();
};

// wraps pointer-to-functions or pointer-to-static-members
class callable_from_function : public callable {
   public:
   callable_from_function(void (*function)())
         : f(function) {}

   void operator()() {
      f();
   };
   private:
   void (*f)();
};
```

---

**The callback class:**

```
// generic wrapper for any callable
// this is the only class which is exposed to the user
class callback : public callable {
   public:
   template<class C>
   callback(C& object, void (C::*method)())
         : c(*new callable_from_object<C>(object, method)) {}
   explicit callback(void (*function)())
         : c(*new callable_from_function(function)) {}
   void operator()() {
      c();
   }
   ~callback() {
      std::cout << "dtor\n"; // check for mem leak
      delete &c;
   }
   private:
   callable& c;
};
```

---

**An API example:**

```
struct X {
  void y() { std::cout << "y\n"; }
  static void z() { std::cout << "z\n"; }
} x;

void w() { std::cout << "w\n"; }

int main(int, char*[]) {
   callback c1(x, &X::y);
   callback c2(X::z);
   callback c3(w);
   c1();
   c2();
   c3();
   return 0;
}
```

---

Thanks a lot !! :-)

Comment: sorry to say it still uses templates. Whats wrong with templates?

Comment: It uses templates internally, but look at the API in "main". No templates. Nothing is wrong with templates in general, I just fell that they are not needed to implement callbacks. Look at callback c1 for instance, I don't need to say callback<X> etc...

Comment: Also, not a callback's type should not depend on the called thing. Is the type of callback<A> different from callback<B>? Conceptually not. These are CALLBACKS it does not matter if it calling something in A or B!

Comment: You are just reimplementing `boost::function`. Use that, instead. Read its code if you want to know how to do it. It's a piece of code done by the top notch of c++ programmers. :)

Comment: Can you answer using boost::function to implement what I want with an API close to mine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284239/callback-in-c-template-member-2/1284374#1284374

Comment: If you think "has no templates" is a positive attribute to apply to a piece of code, go and try to re-implement the STL without templates. I've come across too much code where the author tried to avoid templates like the plague and thus created bloated and redundant code -- the opposite of clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YAY!!!**

**My best solution, using no templates, no dynamic allocation, no inheritance (just as union):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class callback {

   public:

   callback() :
         type(not_a_callback) {}

   template<class C>
   callback(C& object, void (C::*method)()) :
         type(from_object),
         object_ptr(reinterpret_cast<generic*>(&object)),
         method_ptr(reinterpret_cast<void (generic::*) ()>(method)) {}

   template<typename T>
   explicit callback(T function) :
         type(from_function),
         function_ptr((void (*)()) function) {}

   void operator()() {
      switch(type) {
         case from_object:
            (object_ptr ->* method_ptr) ();
            break;
         case from_function:
            function_ptr();
            break;
         default:
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid callback");
      };
   }

   private:

   enum { not_a_callback, from_object, from_function } type;

   class generic;

   union {
      void (*function_ptr)();
      struct {
         generic* object_ptr;
         void (generic::*method_ptr)();
      };
   };

};
```

Ok, its a big ugly, but it is FAST. For 20 million iterations, Boost version takes 11.8s, mine using dynamic alloc takes 9.8s and this using union takes 4.2s. And it is 60% smaller than mine using dynamic alloc, and 130% smaller than boost.

**Edit:** updated default constructor.

Comment: If you loose 6 seconds for using 20 million times. I think I would go with the boost versions. That's not enough improvement to outway the maintainability costs.

Comment: Yeah, you mean in production code? But the point was knowing how to do it. And consider also the fact that boost does much more than I wanted. I want to keep it simple (which = maintainability for me).

Comment: For me as a maintainer coming across your code, nothing is simpler than if you use a library that's well tested, approved, and documented all over the net. OTOH, your code requires a big "Why I did this myself" commentary section in order for me to understand what it's all about.

Comment: Note that you are using an anonymous struct which is a non-standard extension to some compilers. Also your code results in undefined behaviour - for explanation see this great [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/559671/469659) by Adam Rosenfield

Answer (score 5):

You can use placement new. Like, set a maximal limit of size you want to allow `callback` to have, like `16` bytes. Then, put an `unsigned char` buffer into your `callback` class that's exactly that wide, and make sure it's aligned correctly (`GCC` has an attribute for that, and if you are lucky, microsoft has an attribute for that too).

You may also go fairly safe if you use an union, and beside the char buffer put dummies of the types you want to stuff into it - that will ensure proper alignment too.

Then, instead of using normal new, use placement new, like

```
if(placement_allocated< callable_from_object<C> >::value) {
  new ((void*)buffer.p) // union member p is the unsigned char buffer
    callable_from_object<C>(object, method);
  c = (callable*)buffer.p;
} else {
  c = new callable_from_object<C>(object, method);
}
```

Then, make the `c` member a pointer instead. You also need to set a flag so you remember whether you have to call delete in the destructor, or leave the placement buffer alone with explicitly calling the destructor.

That's *basically* how `boost::function` does it. It, however, does a whole lot of other stuff to optimize allocation. It uses its own vtable mechanism to optimize space, and of course is very well tested.

Of course, this is not exactly easy to do. But that seems to be the only thing to do about it.

Comment: Yeah it seems that union is a better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284239/callback-in-c-template-member-2/1284431#1284431

Answer (score 1):

In your example you could remove the new and delete by removing the `callback` class.  This is just a Decorator on `callable_from_object` and `callable_from_object` that provides some syntactic sugar: automatically choosing the correct callable object to delegate to.

However this sugar is nice and you will probably want to keep it. Also you will probably have to place the objects other callable objects on the heap anyway.

To me the bigger question is why are you creating a callback library?  If it is just to practice c++ then that is fine, but there are loads of exaples of these already:

- [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/function.html)
- [boost::singnal and slots](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/signals.html)
- [QT signal and slots](http://doc.trolltech.com/signalsandslots.html)

Why not use one these?

From looking at your example if you keep on the path you are going your solution will converge towards boost::function without its flexibility.  So why not use it?  While I don't beleive that the boost developers are Gods they are very tallented engineers with an excellent peer review process that results in very stong libraries.  I don't think most individuals or organisations can reinvent better libraries.

If your concern is excessive memeory allocation and deallocation the solution is this case would probably be a custom allocator for the various callable subtypes.  But again I prefer to allow other people to research these tecniques and use their libraries.

Comment: I do not agree with your first paragraph. And when you say "why not use one of these", my answer to you is: why not explain to me how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284239/callback-in-c-template-member-2/1284374#1284374

Answer (score 1):

Using boost::function and boost:bind.

```
typedef boost::function<void ()> callback;

int main(int, char*[]) {
   callback d1 = boost::bind(&X::y, &x);
   callback d2 = &X::z;
   callback d3 = w;
   d1();
   d2();
   d3();
   return 0;
}
```

Yeah it works, but it is 20% slower than my implementation (with dynamic allocation) and code is 80% bigger.

PS. I repeated the main code 20 million times. Boost version takes 11.8s, mine takes 9.8s.

**Edit:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284239/callback-in-c-template-member-2/1284431#1284431)

Comment: @Helltone, enable optimizing, then use &x or `ref(x)` to push to bind (otherwise, it copies struct x), and then use (...) initialization instead of = .... Ignore if you already did that :) Also, your class is not anymore near complete. It lacks a working copy mechanism (your callback class crashes if you try to copy it).

Comment: Your class may be smaller, but that is because it is not finished. Copy construction and assignment operator need to be defined if you have an owned RAW pointer (otherwise there is a potential of a crash because of the shallow copy problem).

Comment: There is no owned raw pointer, no need to redefine copy & assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to get rid of new delete as your doing polymorphism and thus it will end up trying to copy the child class into a parent class and loose the child class functionality.

Comment: Yeah I know. callable_from_object and callable_from_function have different sizes. Worse than that, callable_from_object size depends on the size of the pointer to a member, which may be different if the object has virtual table. Yet I hoped that something using an "union" could solve the problem... Any C++ expert out there?

Comment: god dont start using unions. Just use the boost solution or the other template solution, there is nothing to gain by removing the new and templates.

Comment: Can you answer using boost to implement what I want with an API close to mine please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284239/callback-in-c-template-member-2/1284374#1284374